# failed API call - error 400

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, face-detection

I've written a simple API call using requests and am getting an error 400 on executing the call. Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong? Thanks for the help. Here's the code i wrote -

```
 import requests

 params={
    'api_key':'gozbsSP1fxqNSS5YjcFM7qcjjKch1tBB',
    'api_secret':'HklHJCzfO87YyIC9DudGArVKJtioEhbO',
    'image_url':'http://picz.in/data/media/7/study-in-canada-students.jpg'
 }

 r = requests.post(url='https://api-
 us.faceplusplus.com/facepp/v3/detect',data=params)
 print(r)
```

Comment: I hope the api key and secret you included in your post are not your actual credentials...! If they are please edit the post and replace them with random digits

Comment: Yes, these are not my actual credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

400 error code basically means it's a bad request. So it can be that you provided the wrong params for the api, or the api_key or api_secret is not correct. 
Check the documentation of the API whether you are sending all the required params are there or not. If so check your secret keys and make sure it's the correct one.

Remeber to never post you API Keys on public forums like SO...

Comment: Wrong key or secret will usually return a 401 unauthorized not 400 (*usually:) )

Comment: Usually yes... But I have seen API where the developers sent 400 for authorisation errors as well... Basically you can't trust third party API's....

Comment: my api key and api secret are both correct and the documentation of the api is [here](https://console.faceplusplus.com/documents/5679127). I have given all the required parameters. If I'm missing something,please tell me.

Comment: In the documentation it is given that 400 errors has it's own response. Did you check that? There are four cases which are unsupported image format, invalid image size, invalid image url or image file too large... Check to see what your error message is... And looking at your image_url I believe it to be image file too large... Instead of print(r) try r.json() and see the results

Comment: Thanks, that was it. The image file was too large. I didn't realize the size of the image till I actually downloaded it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

400 means its a bad request: the request you made is not what the server wanted.
(invalid arguments, wrong payload data, etc)

More info on 400 errors here: 
https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/400-bad-request

> The 400 Bad Request Error is an HTTP response status code that indicates that the server was unable to process the request sent by the client due to invalid syntax

Sometimes the response object will include information on why the request failed, but that's not always the case.

Comment: I dont think Ive missed any parameters. The documentation clearly asks for the above 3 parameters. In case you need to refer to the documentation of the api, it is given [here](https://console.faceplusplus.com/documents/5679127).

Comment: Maybe you need to set the content type header?
I noticed they have a python SDK. Maybe take a look at the source code and see how they are creating the requests:
https://github.com/FacePlusPlus/python-sdk/blob/master/python-sdk/facepp.py

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the issue has been resolved. The image specified in 'image_url' was too large for the api to process.

Comment: @SoumyaKhurana happy to hear. Thanks for posting back the solution